# Where to access files generated by 'STORE' command in PIG

Tags: apache-pig

In pig, using:

```
STORE rows2 INTO '/usr/data' USING PigStorage('*');
```

The output from terminal after processing data is:

```
Input(s):
Successfully read 42 records (15362 bytes) from: "cassandra://info/playerinfo"

Output(s):
Successfully stored 6916 records (487416 bytes) in: "/usr/data"
```

But when I `cd` to `/usr/data`, I can not find anything generated by Pig. How do I get such files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You data will be stored in HDFS file system.

```
1.Go to http://<hostname>:50070/dfshealth.jsp
2.Click the "Browse the file system" link
3.Go to your output folder  "/usr/data"
```

Comment: I can do the first step, but when click `Browse the file system`, it gives the `This webpage is not available` error. What if the terminal gives `Output(s):
Successfully stored 6916 records (487416 bytes) in: "hdfs://10.6.1.88:9000/user/htdr/pigtestdata"` ?

Comment: when you click the "Browser the file system", it is trying to access the local host, can you replace the localhost to your hostname and try again?

Comment: it should be something like this  http://<hostname>:50075/browseDirectory.jsp?namenodeInfoPort=50070&dir=/

Comment: Can you paste the http link where you got the "webpage not available error"?

Comment: replace "emsbuild10"  to your ip address "10.6.1.88" and access the link